# EventSource keep disconnecting and retrying to connect every 3 seconds

Tags: flask, eventsource

Tried to use event source on flask here is what I did:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

from consts import APP_SECRET_KEY, SERVER_IP
from src.routes import register_routes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = APP_SECRET_KEY
JWTManager(app)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
messages = []


def initApp():
    register_routes(app)

    @app.route('/test')
    def test():
        return "asdasdasd"

    @app.route("/stream")
    def stream():
        def eventStream():
            if len(messages) > 0:
                message = messages.pop(0)
                yield f"data:{message}\nevent:myEvent\n\n"

        return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

    app.run(host=SERVER_IP, debug=True)
```

In the client side(react native) I did this:

```
this._eventSource = new EventSource('http://myip:5000/stream', {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
this._eventSource.addEventListener('myEvent', (ev: any) => {
      console.log(ev.data);
    });
```

I do get the data but in the server I saw this in my console:
[image]

when I added the error event listener it logged to the console the error event, then I checked if EventSource.CLOSED and every few seconds it was true, meaning the connection is lost every few seconds and reestablished again.. What Am I doing wrong here? why the connection is lost?